# Setting a Background Image on Login Screen

Tags: server, login

I have 2 computers 1 it's the server and the other is a client.
In the login screen(client) I have something like that : https://www.thefanclub.co.za/sites/default/files/images/ThinClient.png 
But i want to costumize this login screen without using LightDM is it possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Why dont you want to use LightDM?